# duplication of messages in stderr and stdout python logging

Tags: python, logging

I would like to log info and warning level to stdout and error level and above to stderr how can I do it ?

code:

```
import os
import subprocess
from typing import Union
import logging
import yaml
import logging.config

with open("logging.conf", "r") as f:
    config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
    logging.config.dictConfig(config)


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)    


def run(
    cmd: Union[str, list[str]],
    *,
    cwd: Union[str, os.PathLike[str], None] = None,
    shell: bool = False,
    check: bool = True,
    capture_output: bool = True,
    text: bool = True,
) -> subprocess.CompletedProcess[str]:
    logger.info("start run!!")
    return subprocess.run(cmd, check=True, capture_output=capture_output, text=text)


cmd = ["lxs"]


def main():
    try:
        output = run(cmd)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e, exc_info=False)


main()
```

logging.conf

```
version: 1
formatters:
  simple:
    format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
handlers:
  outconsole:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: INFO
    formatter: simple
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
  errconsole:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: WARNING
    formatter: simple
    stream: ext://sys.stderr

  file_handler:
    class: logging.FileHandler
    level: INFO
    formatter: simple
    filename: info.log
    encoding: utf8
    mode: w

loggers:
  sampleLogger:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [file_handler]
    propagate: no
root:
  level: INFO
  handlers: [errconsole, outconsole, file_handler]
  propagate: no
```

and output after `python3 -m tests 1> output.log 2> err.log`:

err.log

```
2022-10-14 14:34:02,354 - __main__ - ERROR - [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lxs'
```

output.log

```
2022-10-14 14:34:02,353 - __main__ - INFO - start run!!
2022-10-14 14:34:02,354 - __main__ - ERROR - [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lxs'
```

Consequently, the output on the console is:

```
2022-10-14 14:48:33,178 - __main__ - INFO - start run!!
2022-10-14 14:48:33,179 - __main__ - ERROR - [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lxs'
2022-10-14 14:48:33,179 - __main__ - ERROR - [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lxs'
```

My question is how to make the message not repeat itself ? I want ERROR on strerr and INFO on stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way levels work in `logging`, if you want to restrict `stdout` to `WARNING` and below and restrict `stderr` to `ERROR` and above, you'll need to employ filters in the solution. One way of doing it is as follows.

First, add a `filters` entry parallel to `formatters` and `handlers`, to define a couple of filters:

```
filters:
  warnings_and_below:
    "()": __main__.filter_maker
    level: WARNING
    sense: below
  errors_and_above:
    "()": __main__.filter_maker
    level: ERROR
    sense: above
```

and refer to them in the handler configurations:

```
filters: [warnings_and_below]  # for outconsole
```

and

```
filters: [errors_and_above]  # for errconsole
```

Filters are just functions, and we'll define `filter_maker` as follows:

```
def filter_maker(level, sense):
    level = getattr(logging, level)  # get the actual numeric value from the string
    if sense == 'below':  # return a function which only passes if level is at or below threshold
        def filter(record):
            return record.levelno <= level
    else:  # return a function which only passes if level is at or above threshold
        def filter(record):
            return record.levelno >= level
    return filter
```

I'm using a small script and running it directly, and so the `filter_maker` will be in the `__main__` module (as indicated in the "()" lines above). You might need to change that to fit your specific situation.

Now, if I add some lines to log stuff:

```
logging.config.dictConfig(...)
logging.debug('A DEBUG message')
logging.info('An INFO message')
logging.warning('A WARNING message')
logging.error('An ERROR message')
logging.critical('A CRITICAL message')
```

and suppose all this is in `main.py`, then you can run

```
python main.py 2>stderr.log >stdout.log
```

and then you should see what's expected:

```
$ more stdout.log 
2022-10-14 16:41:09,867 - root - INFO - An INFO message
2022-10-14 16:41:09,867 - root - WARNING - A WARNING message

$ more stderr.log
2022-10-14 16:41:09,868 - root - ERROR - An ERROR message
2022-10-14 16:41:09,868 - root - CRITICAL - A CRITICAL message

$ more info.log
2022-10-14 16:41:09,867 - root - INFO - An INFO message
2022-10-14 16:41:09,867 - root - WARNING - A WARNING message
2022-10-14 16:41:09,868 - root - ERROR - An ERROR message
2022-10-14 16:41:09,868 - root - CRITICAL - A CRITICAL message
```